# Removing from a hashmap

Tags: hashmap, int

Ok, so I have this easy bit of code, but I can't figure out why it doesn't work ...

```
int redscre = teamScore.get(TeamType.RED);
int redscore = redscre--;
teamScore.put(TeamType.RED, redscore);
```

Comment: what is the error/behaviour that you get?

Comment: I fixed it with changing int redscore = redscre -1; but I still don't understand why redscre--; didn't work ...

Comment: that is because post-decrement operator will decrease the value after assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the post-decrement operator that's tripping you up:

```
int redscore = redscre--;
```

This is the sequence of events that occur:

1. The value of `redscre` gets assigned to `redscore`
2. `redscre` is decremented, `redscore` is unchanged

Then you put the unchanged value of `redscore` back into the hashmap.

Change to the pre-decrement operator to make it work:

```
int redscre = teamScore.get(TeamType.RED);
teamScore.put(TeamType.RED, --redscre);
```

Or if you want to do things more explicitly:

```
int redscre = teamScore.get(TeamType.RED);
int redscore = redscre - 1;
teamScore.put(TeamType.RED, redscore);
```

This [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators) provides a good explanation about the differences between pre- and post-increment/decrement operators.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using the post decrement operator.

Redscrore is set to the value of redscr and then redsrc is decremented

Try this:

```
int redscre = teamScore.get(TeamType.RED);
int redscore = redscre - 1;  // This statement returns the proper value.
teamScore.put(TeamType.RED, redscore);
```

Another solution would be to use the pre-decrements operator (redscroe = --redscr), but seeing as redscr is just a temporary, there really isn't a good reason to do this.